# Get second value from a list of structure in racket?

Tags: list, struct, racket

Suppose a list in racket contains `(cons (make-card 'spades 8) (cons (make-card 'hearts 3) empty))`

```
  (define-struct card(suit value))

  (card-suit(first(cons (make-card 'spades 8) (cons (make-card 'hearts 3) empty))))
  --> give me 'spades
  what to do to get hearts
```

If i write

```
 (rest(first(cons (make-card 'spades 8)(cons (make-card 'hearts 3) empty))))
```

I am getting error

```
rest: expects a non-empty list; given: (make-card 'spades 8)
```

Comment: You want the first element of the rest, not the rest of the first element.

Comment: @melpomene thanks beginner here!

Answer (score 0):

As @melpomene says, you have your `first` and `rest` reversed.

The error says that `rest` was given `(make-card 'spades 8)`, which is the first item in your list.  Instead you want to get the `rest` of your list (so you have a list that starts with `(make-card 'hearts 3)`) and then take the `first` of that (to get the card at the start of that shorter list).